# separate log files for multiple deployments under one server - weblogic

Tags: logging, weblogic

In our Weblogic, we have one server(e.g. myserver) configured through the admin portal. There are 3 spring boot applications(e.g. app1, app2, app3) running on the same server.

So, the log statements for all the applications are written to the same server(e.g `DOMAIN_NAME\servers\myserver\logs\myserver.log`)

Can we change the configuration so that 3 different log files can be created? We are using `slf4j` for logging. Can we override the logging of weblogic by specifying the log location such as `log4j.appender.file.File=/path/to/folder/app1.log`?

Comment: WebLogic Server will always handle its own loggin file and it is not possible to change its behavior. You should handle your logs at the level application with SLF4J.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin Weblogic provides useful feature collecting logs of the different server into a single domain log. How it is intended to be used without log splitting per application?